# stop an external hard disk from being in group floppy

Tags: hard-disk, udev

I have an external hard-disk, connected by usb. Because it is external, the /dev file for it is in group floppy. However I use it as if it is internal. I also sometimes format sd cards and other usb devices, I am in group floppy to do this. I do not want to accidentally format this hard-disk, so do not want it to be in group floppy.

How can I configure it to be in a different group. It is currently managed by udev. I have not been able to figure out how to configure udev.

I am using Debian 7 (Wheezy)

Answer (score 1):

A simple UDEV rule like that should help:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{idVendor}=="058f", ATTRS{idProduct}=="6366", GROUP="disk"
```

Add it to, say, `/etc/udev/rules.d/92-treat-my-usb-drive-as-internal.rules`, so it would be proccessed after `91-permissions.rules`, which assign the `floppy` group.

`idVendor` and `idProduct` of your USB-drive could be detected with `$ lsusb`:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
<...>
```

Please note, that they are not quite unique: they identify model, not an every single device. If it is a problem to you, you could look in `$ udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdx` for something more unique.

By the way, in Jessie, `91-permissions.rules` is dropped (see bug [#751892](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=751892)), so you also have to prepare to do the opposite after upgrading in order to keep formatting SD-cards.

Comment: That looks like it will do what I want. Can I use disk labels (the things that appear in `/dev/disk/by-label`).

Comment: @richard Try to figure out: `SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_FS_LABEL_ENC}=="MYSTORAGE", GROUP="disk"` :-)

Comment: @richard I think, that it would work correctly, but the correct result is not that you expect: labels are assigned to *partitions*, so the partition (say, `/dev/sdb1`) would belong to group `disk`, while the whole disk (`/dev/sdb`) – still to group `floppy`, so that one still might wipe it without superuser rights.